# Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null when extending from a class/interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a class that looks like this:

```js
class TextElement extends ProjectElement {
    initialize() {
        this.name = "Text"
        this.elementID = "text"
        this.properties.addProperty(new ElementProperty("text", "Hi!"))
    }

    render(): any {
        return <div>
            {this.properties.getProp("text")}
        </div>
    }
}
```

In my editor, it's all good (InteliSense doesn't throw any errors). But as soon as I enter the browser (in my case, my Electron app), I get this error:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at eval (TextElement.tsx:9:37)
    at ./src/libs/elements/TextElement.tsx (main.js:993:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:1455:42)
    at eval (list.ts:6:39)
    at ./src/libs/elements/list.ts (main.js:1004:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:1455:42)
    at eval (project.tsx:10:32)
    at ./src/libs/project.tsx (main.js:1037:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:1455:42)
    at eval (Editor.tsx:45:35)
```

What I think is happening is that `TextElement` is not extending the class `ProjectElement`, but rather the type/interface `ProjectElement`, so that when I use the `new` keyword, TypeScript finds no `constructor()` function.

I could define the `constructor()` manually but that defeats the purpose of inheriting entirely. If I want to add another one, I'd need to copy/paste code around which as we all know is not efficient.

`tsconfig.js`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */

    /* Projects */
    // "incremental": true,                              /* Save .tsbuildinfo files to allow for incremental compilation of projects. */
    // "composite": true,                                /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./.tsbuildinfo",              /* Specify the path to .tsbuildinfo incremental compilation file. */
    // "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": true,  /* Disable preferring source files instead of declaration files when referencing composite projects. */
    // "disableSolutionSearching": true,                 /* Opt a project out of multi-project reference checking when editing. */
    // "disableReferencedProjectLoad": true,             /* Reduce the number of projects loaded automatically by TypeScript. */

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2016",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    // "lib": [],                                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
    "jsx": "react",                                /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,                   /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                    /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */
    // "jsxFactory": "",                                 /* Specify the JSX factory function used when targeting React JSX emit, e.g. 'React.createElement' or 'h'. */
    // "jsxFragmentFactory": "",                         /* Specify the JSX Fragment reference used for fragments when targeting React JSX emit e.g. 'React.Fragment' or 'Fragment'. */
    // "jsxImportSource": "",                            /* Specify module specifier used to import the JSX factory functions when using 'jsx: react-jsx*'. */
    // "reactNamespace": "",                             /* Specify the object invoked for 'createElement'. This only applies when targeting 'react' JSX emit. */
    // "noLib": true,                                    /* Disable including any library files, including the default lib.d.ts. */
    // "useDefineForClassFields": true,                  /* Emit ECMAScript-standard-compliant class fields. */
    // "moduleDetection": "auto",                        /* Control what method is used to detect module-format JS files. */

    /* Modules */
    "module": "CommonJS",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "rootDir": "./",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",                       /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
    // "paths": {},                                      /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                                   /* Allow multiple folders to be treated as one when resolving modules. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                                  /* Specify multiple folders that act like './node_modules/@types'. */
    // "types": [],                                      /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                     /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
    // "moduleSuffixes": [],                             /* List of file name suffixes to search when resolving a module. */
    // "resolveJsonModule": true,                        /* Enable importing .json files. */
    // "noResolve": true,                                /* Disallow 'import's, 'require's or '<reference>'s from expanding the number of files TypeScript should add to a project. */

    /* JavaScript Support */
    // "allowJs": true,                                  /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */
    // "checkJs": true,                                  /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */
    // "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 1,                        /* Specify the maximum folder depth used for checking JavaScript files from 'node_modules'. Only applicable with 'allowJs'. */

    /* Emit */
    // "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
    // "emitDeclarationOnly": true,                      /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                                /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
    // "outFile": "./",                                  /* Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If 'declaration' is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output. */
    "outDir": "./ts-build",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    // "removeComments": true,                           /* Disable emitting comments. */
    // "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                            /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
    // "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",               /* Specify emit/checking behavior for imports that are only used for types. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,                       /* Emit more compliant, but verbose and less performant JavaScript for iteration. */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                                 /* Specify the root path for debuggers to find the reference source code. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                            /* Include source code in the sourcemaps inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "emitBOM": true,                                  /* Emit a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the beginning of output files. */
    // "newLine": "crlf",                                /* Set the newline character for emitting files. */
    // "stripInternal": true,                            /* Disable emitting declarations that have '@internal' in their JSDoc comments. */
    // "noEmitHelpers": true,                            /* Disable generating custom helper functions like '__extends' in compiled output. */
    // "noEmitOnError": true,                            /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */
    // "preserveConstEnums": true,                       /* Disable erasing 'const enum' declarations in generated code. */
    // "declarationDir": "./",                           /* Specify the output directory for generated declaration files. */
    // "preserveValueImports": true,                     /* Preserve unused imported values in the JavaScript output that would otherwise be removed. */

    /* Interop Constraints */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                            /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,                         /* When type checking, take into account 'null' and 'undefined'. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                      /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,                      /* Check that the arguments for 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods match the original function. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,             /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when 'this' is given the type 'any'. */
    // "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,               /* Default catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                             /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when local variables aren't read. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,                       /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read. */
    // "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,               /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,                        /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,               /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,                 /* Add 'undefined' to a type when accessed using an index. */
    // "noImplicitOverride": true,                       /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */
    // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,       /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type. */
    // "allowUnusedLabels": true,                        /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */
    // "allowUnreachableCode": true,                     /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */

    /* Completeness */
    // "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:** After changing `module` to something other than `CommonJS`, I get a new error:

```js
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ProjectElement' before initialization
    at Module.ProjectElement (project.tsx:6:63)
    at eval (TextElement.tsx:11:65)
    at ./src/libs/elements/TextElement.tsx (main.js:993:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:1345:41)
    at eval (list.ts:5:70)
    at ./src/libs/elements/list.ts (main.js:1004:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:1345:41)
    at eval (project.tsx:12:72)
    at ./src/libs/project.tsx (main.js:1037:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:1345:41)
```

This is due to a circular-import mess between 3 files.

`project.tsx`

```js
import React from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';

import ELEMENT_LIST from './elements/list';

interface Project {
    elements: {
        [key: string]: ProjectElement
    }
    name: string
    id: string
}

interface ProjectElement {
    uid: string
    properties: ElementProperties
    name: string
    render(): any,
    elementID: string
}

interface ElementProperty {
    value: any
    name: string
    uid: string
    editable: boolean
}

interface ElementProperties {
    properties: {
        [key: string]: ElementProperty
    }
}

class Project {
    constructor() {
        this.elements = {}
        this.name = ""
        this.id = ""
    }

    addElement(element: ProjectElement) {
        this.elements[element.uid] = element
    }

    serialize() {
        // Serialize elements
        let serializedElements: {
            [key: string]: {}
        } = {}
        Object.keys(this.elements).map((element_key) => {
            const element: ProjectElement = this.elements[element_key]
            const serializedElement = element.serialize()
            serializedElements[element.uid] = serializedElement
        })

        return {
            name: this.name,
            elements: serializedElements,
        }
    }

    load(json: any) {
        const elements: {
            [key: string]: any
        } = json.elements
        const name: string = json.name

        this.name = name
        this.id = json.id
        Object.keys(elements).map(key => {
            const element = elements[key]
            const elementID: string = element.elementID
            const ElementConstructor = ELEMENT_LIST[elementID]
            const newElement = new ElementConstructor()
            newElement.load(element)
            this.addElement(newElement)
        })
    }
}
class ProjectElement {
    constructor() {
        this.uid = uuidV4()
        this.name = "Element"
        this.elementID = "generic"
        this.properties = new ElementProperties()

        this.initialize()
        this.render = this.render.bind(this)
    }

    serialize() {
        return {
            uid: this.uid,
            properties: this.properties.getAllProps(),
            elementID: this.elementID
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            Here you put your custom component logic!
        </div>
    }

    initialize() {
        console.log(`Component "${this.uid}" initialized!`)
    }

    load(json: any) {
        this.uid = json.uid
        this.name = json.name
        this.elementID = json.elementID
        this.properties.loadProperties(json.properties)
    }
}

class ElementProperties {
    constructor() {
        this.properties = {};
    }

    addProperty(property: ElementProperty) {
        this.properties[property.name] = property
    }

    updateProperty(name: string, value: any) {
        this.properties[name].changeValue(value)
    }

    deleteProperty(name: string) {
        delete this.properties[name]
    }

    getProp(name: string) {
        let property = this.properties[name]
        return property.value
    }

    getAllProps() {
        let properties: {
            [key: string]: any
        } = {}
        Object.keys(this.properties).map((property_key: string) => {
            const property = this.properties[property_key]
            properties[property_key] = property.value
        })
        return properties
    }

    loadProperties(json: {
        [key: string]: any
    }) {
        Object.keys(json).map(key => {
            const property = json[key]
            const newProperty = new ElementProperty(property.name, property.value)
            this.addProperty(newProperty)
        })
    }
}

class ElementProperty {
    constructor(name: string, value: any) {
        this.value = value
        this.name = name
        this.uid = uuidV4()
        this.editable = true
    }

    changeValue(newValue: any) {
        this.value = newValue
    }

    serialize() {
        return {
            name: this.name,
            value: this.value,
            uid: this.uid,
            editable: this.editable
        }
    }
}

export default Project
export {
    ProjectElement,
    ElementProperty,
    ElementProperties,
    ELEMENT_LIST
}
```

`TextElement.tsx`

```
Mentioned above
```

```
import TextElement from "./TextElement";

const ELEMENT_LIST: {[key: string]: any} = {
    "text": TextElement
}

export default ELEMENT_LIST
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense for a class to extend a type/interface.  TypeScript thinks `ProjectElement` is an actual class constructor.  Unfortunately in your runtime environment it isn't.  This sounds like a mismatch between your `--lib` values (the libraries TS assumes exist at runtime) and your actual runtime environment.  I don't know anything about react so I can't say if this is a common or uncommon issue, but I think in any case people will need details about your runtime configuration to assist.

Comment: @jcalz So my webpack config or my TS config?

Comment: @jcalz I've added my `tsconfig.json` file. Please take a look at it. `lib` is commented out, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Okay it's an entirely separate issue: even though my IDE and compiler says that the import is valid, when imported the result is `undefined`. So I'm essentially importing variables that have the value `undefined`. I'll create a separate question because this is a totally different error.

Comment: You probably have a circular dependency somewhere. Your module is set to `CommonJS`, which does not support circular dependencies. Therefore, when you run your code, the circular dependency doesn't exist yet and so it is `undefined`.

Comment: @vera. Ah okay. I think I've found the circular dependency problem. So I should set `module` to something like `esnext` or something?

Comment: I've updated the question with the files affected by the issue.

Comment: Yes, you should switch to `esnext`. Also, the circular dependency is only in `./elements/list.ts` and `project.tsx`. `TextElement` only causes the error because it is dependent on one of these circular dependencies.

Comment: @vera. I'm getting a separate error (was added in the update).

Comment: Oh you're using webpack... which doesn't support circular dependencies if it's just one file. You'll find [this article](https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de) helpful.

Comment: @vera. aha! Thank you for the article. It's now fixed. You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it.